# Close URLs 1 by 1 after opening (reading URLs from text file, loop)

Tags: file, loops, url, text, vbscript

I have a VBScript that loops through URLs in a text file and opens them.  It opens one every 60 seconds.  I want to close each after about 15 minutes.  I tried `ie.quit` before the loop, but it kills them all.  I only want to close the first page after it's been open ~15 minutes, then the next page, etc.  Basically, as each page opens, each begins its 15-minute countdown to close.  How can I accomplish this?

```
Set IE = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
navflags = 1
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

URLFilename = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\URLsClean.txt"
Set URLFile = fso.OpenTextFile(URLFilename)

do while not URLFile.AtEndOfStream
fName = URLFile.ReadLine()

ie.navigate2 fName,navflags

wscript.sleep 60000

loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the `ShellWindows` collection to iterate the open Internet Explorer windows/tabs and close the appropriate one. It sounds like you're going to need some kind of "close queue" to maintain the next window/URL that needs to be closed.

Here's an example of how to iterate the open IE windows/tabs and close the one with a given URL:

```
Dim objWindow

' Iterate all open shell windows...
For Each objWindow In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows

    ' Make sure this is an Internet Explorer window/tab...
    If StrComp(objWindow.Name, "Internet Explorer", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

        ' Is this the URL that's expired?
        If StrComp(objWindow.LocationURL, strUrlExpired, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

            objWindow.Quit

        End If

    End If

Next
```

Comment: This looks promising, but not sure how to use this in conjunction with the script I have.  Seems like I'd need to loop this somehow and compare this to each line in the text file...

Comment: Right, that's why I mentioned you're going to need some kind of queue to keep track of URLs that are set to expire. I'm showing you how you can close a tab based on the URL (to solve your issue of IE closing completely) but I'm not sure how you planned on closing these after 15 minutes.

Comment: Beyond my current skill level, but I'll start Google'ing.  Thanks.

Comment: Just had a thought - Maybe this script could call another vbscript that runs simultaneously and monitors the open windows/compares with the url file...

Comment: That might work. Your question was pretty broad so I just addressed your immediate issue (IE closing completely instead of an individual tab/page). Try your idea out and, if it doesn't work out, submit a new question with your latest code. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I got it.  This does what I need when I call it separately.

```
Set sa = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set windows = sa.Windows()

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

on error resume next

URLFilename = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\URLsClean.txt"

Set URLFile = fso.OpenTextFile(URLFilename)

do while not URLFile.AtEndOfStream
fName = URLFile.ReadLine()

For Each window In sa.windows

'wscript.echo window.locationurl & " " &  fname

If window.LocationUrl = fname Then
        If UCase(window.locationUrl) = UCase(fname) Then window.Quit()
End If
Next

wscript.sleep 1200000 ' (20 minutes)
loop
```